# Quais são as formas de transferência de dados disponíveis para JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

É comum encontrarmos perguntas, respostas e tutoriais falando de AJAX, que nada mais que o `XMLHttpRequest`, como uma forma de transferência de dados entre dois computadores.

*Queria saber se há outras formas*, sejam elas padronizadas ou proprietárias, limitadas em alguma condição ou abertas a qualquer usuário e site. Um exemplo de uma forma limitada, se há, seria uma API restrita a extensões.

Em especial, mas não restringindo, estou procurando uma forma de transferir dados - algo entre 10 a 30 bytes - da maneira mais rápida possível entre dois computadores dentro da mesma rede. Peer-to-Peer seria ideal, mas não sei se JS suporta. Já usei testei serviços como o [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), que permitiu um tempo mínimo de resposta, porém, usando um servidor fora da rede e com ocasional perda de dados.

Conhecendo outras formas queria encontrar uma que permitisse se adequasse melhor ao que estou desenvolvendo. Não parece que a resposta será algo grande: as opções parecem ser bem limitadas, uma vez que parece que só o AJAX é usado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem várias APIs que vão lhe permitir transportar dados via Javascript.

Sendo que algumas vão apenas lhe permitir receber dados, outras vão lhe permitir enviar e receber.

As que lhe permite enviar e receber dados são:

- `XMLHttpRequest`

  - Requisições via protocolo HTTP
- `WebSocket`

  - É um protocolo cross-compatível com HTTP focado em trocas de mensagem mais leve e rápido que por requisição, porém não tem uma resolução de estados tão eficiente quanto `XMLHttpRequest`
  - [Especificação da W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/)
- `WebRTC`

  - Protocolo para troca de dados Peer-to-peer, foi criado para resolver o problema de transmissões de vídeo e áudio entre browsers.
  - [Especificação da W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/)

Se a transmissão de dados precisa ser p2p, o ideal é utilizar o WebRTC, porém ainda é um tanto complexo criar um servidor que faça o handshake entre dois browsers e inicie a comunicação.

Uma solução mais simples é o uso de **WebSockets**, porém toda informação passará por um servidor que vai receber os dados de um client e irá envia-los a outro ou outros clients. Mas o websocket tem a restrição de trabalhar com UTF-8, porém é possível usar conversores de dados para converter os dados binários para UTF-8 antes de serem transmitidos e novamente pro formato original quando recebidos, existem várias maneiras, uma delas é usando o `Uint8Array`.

Comment: Como eu disse *parece mesmo muito limitado*: ajax tenho que usar pooling ou conexões longas, websockets é a tecnologia que o firebase usa, webrtc tem problemas piores de perca de dados (em relação ao anterior).

Comment: Conforme você vai editando essa resposta isso vai desenvolvendo: como o PunchTheNewbie falou eu vou acabar tendo que usar um servidor Socket.IO dentro da rede. Sem outras alternativas.

Comment: Se você usar o Socket.io, ele vai conforme o suporte do browser usar a conexão que puder das versões de websocket protocol até chegar em pushstream e por fim usando flash se o browser tiver suporte. O WebRTC usa UDP, o que não vai te garantir entrega de pacotes, vais ter que trabalhar com carrocel e fazer sumcheck pra garantir as entregas.

Comment: Estou deixando essa pergunta um pouco genérica pois ela tem no mínimo duas aplicações para mim, uma delas é apresentação de slides: já cansei de passar o slide em um computador e não atualizar nos outros. Por isso preocupo com a perda de dados.

Comment: Sincronização de slides é muito fácil e eficiente com websocket, no evento de conexão vc sincroniza o client com host e depois é só mandar as alterações de estado pra replicar de um no outro. O http://meteor.com é uma boa framework pra fazer isso de forma rápida e eficiente. Eu tenho um demo com jogo de damas em http://damas.gartz.com.br porém ele não faz a sincronia inicial ainda, só as subsequentes, abra em 2 computadores e ele vai replicar as ações nos dois por websocket.

Comment: Já testei isso no mínimo com duas situações diferentes: duas apresentações para meus professores e duas com minha família (melhores beta testers que já vi). Uma usava JSON pooling e as outras websockets. Delas três falharam e tive que controlar manualmente. A que funcionou usava Socket.IO. Estou procurando por outra forma mas parece que não há.

Comment: Socket.IO usa pooling caso não tenha suporte a websocket no browser, entre outros fallbacks como eu já expliquei. Mas o problema não é no protocolo, acho que é na implementação que vc fez. Pois se você garantir estado na conexão e depois fazer troca de mensagens não tem como dar erro. Pois se der erro, ele vai reconectar por tanto vai recuperar o estado antes de executar as próximas mensagens.

Comment: Dr. acho que a sua melhor chance é com Socket.IO. Se optar por essa implementação, não se esqueça de dar crédito à minha resposta nesse thread. Isso evita que futuros usuários entendam que você usou outra alternativa. Ab.

Comment: e se ele usar uma das várias alternativas ao socket.io? afinal essa é só a mais conhecida e com mais bugs das libs de websocket... tem a socksjs por exemplo que é usada pelo meteorjs e se procurar vai achar outras alternativas.

Answer (score 6):

Sugiro utilizar o Socket IO, uma extensão em javascript já adaptada para uso em cross-browser e que tem uma vantagem extra, ela escolhe a maneira mais eficiente de transportar dados entre as tecnologias abaixo (que são a resposta a sua pergunta):

**1) WebSocket;

2) Adobe Flash Socket;

3) AJAX long polling;

4) AJAX multipart streaming;

5) Forever iframe;

6) JSONP Polling.**

Ainda, essa extensão tem uma compatibilidade excelente: IE 5.5+ ; Safari 3+ ; Chrome 4+; Firefox 3+; Opera 10.61+; Iphone/Ipad Safari; Android Webkit e WebOs Webkit.

**http://socket.io/#how-to-use**

Tive excelentes experiências com essa extensão. Quando se opta por um caminho onde os fallbacks já estão incluídos tudo fica mais fácil!

Boa Sorte!